# ui-router display raw code in my ui-views when the page is accessed

Tags: html, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

This is my first time using `ui-router` and I find difficulties in handling routing and reloading some states. I hope anyone can help me with this.

**overview of my index.html**

```
<html ng-app="resApp">
   <head></head>
   <body ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-cloak>
     <div ng-show="showCustomerContent">  
         <div id="page-wrapper">
              <div ui-view="header"></div>
              <div ui-view="slider" ng-show="displaySlider"></div>
              <div ui-view="content"></div>
              <div ui-view="footer"></div>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div ng-show="showAdminContent">
          <div id="page-wrapper">
              <div ui-view="aheader"></div>
              <div ui-view="asidebar"></div>
              <div id="page-content-wrapper">
              <div id="page-content">
                   <div class="container-fluid">
                       <div ui-view="acontent"></div>
                   </div>
              </div>
     </div>
     <div ui-view="jsincludes"></div>

   </body>
</html>
```

**routing.js**

```
    'use strict'
        resApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$httpProvider','$locationProvider',function ($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider,$locationProvider) {
                $urlRouterProvider
                .when('/','/Home')
                .when('/login','/Home')
                .otherwise('/Home');

                $stateProvider
                .state("home",{
                url:'/Home',
                views:{
                    'jsincludes':{
                        templateUrl:'views/includes/jsincludes.html'
                    },
                    'header':{
                        templateUrl:'views/customer_part/header.html',
                    controller:'headerCtrl'
                    },
                    'slider':{
                        templateUrl:'views/customer_part/slider.html'
                    },
                    'footer':{
                        templateUrl:'views/customer_part/footer.html'
                    }
                }

              })
              .state("home.aboutus",{
                 url:"/AboutUs",
                 views:{
                     'content@':{
                     templateUrl:'views/customer_views/aboutus.html',
                     controller:'aboutusCtrl'
                          }
                       }
              })
              $httpProvider.useApplyAsync(true);
         }]);
```

**controller.js**

```
'use strict'
resApp.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope','$location','UserData','$rootScope',function($scope,$location,UserData,$rootScope){
    $rootScope.displaySlider = true;
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(event, toState){
        var url = $location.absUrl().split('/');
        //console.log(url);
        if(url.length > 6){
            $rootScope.displaySlider = false;
        }else{
            $rootScope.displaySlider = true;
        }

    });

    UserData.getSessVar().then(function(msg){
        if(msg.data!="none"){
            $rootScope.uid = msg.data["uid"];
            $rootScope.fullname = msg.data["fullname"];
            $rootScope.role = msg.data["role"];
            $rootScope.Id = msg.data["Id"];
            if($rootScope.role == "customer"){
                $scope.showCustomerContent = true;
            }else{
                $scope.showAdminContent = true;
            }
        }else{
            $rootScope.role = "none";
            $scope.showCustomerContent = true;
        }

    });


}]);
resApp.controller('headerCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope','UserData','$location','$state','$stateParams',function($scope,$rootScope,UserData,$location,$state,$stateParams){
    $scope.hideLoginBtn = false;
    if($rootScope.uid!=undefined){
        $scope.hideLoginBtn = true;
    }

    $scope.logout = function(){
        UserData.logoutUser($rootScope.Id).then(function(msg){
            if(msg.data=="success"){
                window.location.reload();
                //$location.path('/Home');
            }
        });
    }

    $scope.home = function(){
        $state.go('home', {}, { reload: true });
    }

    $scope.aboutus = function(){
        $state.go('home.aboutus',{},{reload:true});
    }
}]);

resApp.controller('aheaderCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope','UserData','$location',function($scope,$rootScope,UserData,$location){
    $scope.logout = function(){
        UserData.logoutUser($rootScope.Id).then(function(msg){
            if(msg.data=="success"){
                window.location.reload();
                //$location.path('/Home');
            }

        });
    }
}]);
```

**In my header.html I have this code**

```
<li>
    <a href="" title="Home" ng-click="home()">
       Home
    </a>
</li>
```

[image: Image when I click Home]

Whenever I click `Home` the `index.html` is displaying another copy of my header and slider. As you can see in the image the `{{fullname}}` scope was displayed and also the other `ui-views`. I tried doing the `ui-sref="home" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}"` and put it in my anchor tag but the result is the same. I need to reload the page because my slider is not displaying if I just do `ui-sref="home"`. I also tried to use the `ng-cloak` but whenever I click the anchor tag it also display my raw code in angularjs. The displayed raw code disappear when the whole page was rendered. Can anyone help me with this?

**Update**
This error only appeared in mozilla firefox. My routing is perfectly fine in chrome

Comment: Which version of angular and ui-router are you using? I wanted to recreate this issue in some online code editor.

Comment: I used the latest version of it sir

Comment: Could you make a Plunker of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is div tag closing issue on the below code

```
<div ng-show="showAdminContent">
          <div id="page-wrapper">
              <div ui-view="aheader"></div>
              <div ui-view="asidebar"></div>
              <div id="page-content-wrapper">
              <div id="page-content">
                   <div class="container-fluid">
                       <div ui-view="acontent"></div>
                   </div>
              </div>
     </div>
```

Change it as below

```
<div ng-show="showAdminContent">
          <div id="page-wrapper">
              <div ui-view="aheader"></div>
              <div ui-view="asidebar"></div>
              <div id="page-content-wrapper">
              <div id="page-content">
                   <div class="container-fluid">
                       <div ui-view="acontent"></div>
                   </div>
              </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

Also, I am not sure why are you keeping header, footer, and slider as a named ui-view while you can achieve the same using simple ng-include. Use routing only for redirection and hyperlinks.

Refer my plunker for how to do it

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZatFwz83ODsPjy55eRc5?p=preview

Comment: Oh I never check it. Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should have another html file ex:- main.html and in main.html specify the ui-view. for ex:-

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view></div>
<div ui-view="footer"></div>
```

Comment: I will try this sir